# sitemap and canonical url for website that has only one page: "index.html" hosted using GitHub Pages

Tags: seo, google-search-console, html, canonical-url, xml-sitemap

I have the almost same question as this:

- [How do I correctly add index page to xml sitemap - do I need a canonical expression?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109665/how-do-i-correctly-add-index-page-to-xml-sitemap-do-i-need-a-canonical-express)

But I am confused with the accepted answer, as for my case, the website is hosted using `GitHub Pages` and has only one html in root directory: `index.html`

```
.
├── assets
├── index.html
├── manifest.json
├── robots.txt
├── sitemap.xml
```

So, What should be my `sitemap.xml` and `canonical url` in `index.html` ?

Should it be like this? `sitemap.xml`:

```
<url>
  <loc>https://example.github.io/</loc>
  <lastmod>2021-10-19</lastmod>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
```

and in `index.html`

```
<link rel="canonical" href="/"/>
```

I am very new to this and would appreciate a specific answer to this.

**For more info:**

Currently my sitemap only contains `https://example.github.io/` and no canonical url in *index.html*

Google Search Console url inspection for `https://example.github.io/` says:

> Coverage [Indexed, not submitted in sitemap]

> Sitemaps: N/A

> User-declared canonical: None

> Google-selected canonical: Inspected URL

Comment: Is your webpage accessible at both `https://example.github.io/` and `https://example.github.io/index.html`? Which URL do you use to access the page through? Which one do you prefer? The canonical URL is your preferred URL.

Comment: @MrWhite yes both are accessible. `https://example.github.io/` is my preferred URL. [This](https://thermo-state.github.io/) is the actual URL, I am talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you're receiving from Google "Indexed, not submitted in sitemap" is typical of any page Google finds through any means other than a sitemap.  It's not an error.

If you only have one page, index.html and Google has already found it, you really don't need a sitemap.  Sitemaps are not necessary in most cases and Google seems to prefer finding pages via links.  A site can have many pages in a sitemap, and GGC will refer to the majority of them via the message you have received.  It simply means the pages were found through other means first.

See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

**Additional information**

Additionally, sitemaps are designed to point to URLs you want indexed (that maybe can't be found via other methods).  These can include both the top of your domain, as in example.com, and pages such as example.com/index.html.

In regards to canonicals, a canonical is meant to point the user to another similar or identical page.  It's designed to tell search engines the original source for content.  However, putting a canonical link on your home page is also considered good practice.  You can use something similar to `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/">` in your header.  Or in your situation, `<link rel="canonical"  ref="https://example.github.io/">`

See also [Should homepage be set up as canonical?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122526/should-homepage-be-set-up-as-canonical)

Comment: I got you but what would be correct way to write sitemap for this case anyway? Should sitemap include both "example.github.io" and "example.github.io/index.html" or only one of these? And, should there be `<link rel="canonical" href="/"/>` in index.html?

Comment: @ShihabusSakibRad see modification to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was confused because example.com and example.com/index.html refers to same page {index.html}, but [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap) it says only to List canonical URLs in sitemaps. And, regarding canonical url, can href be only "/" instead of example.com as both are same, i guess?

Comment: I got the answer of my last question from [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls). **Use absolute paths rather than relative paths with the rel="canonical" link tag**